# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException after upgrading to SDK 21.1 and ADT 21.1

Tags: android

I recently upgraded my eclipse with ADT 21.1.

I'm able to run apps as debug perfectly, but after exporting the apk and installing it on my smartphone it allways crashes, giving the follow error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application 
com.tapcrowd.app.TCApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tapcrowd.app.TCApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/mnt/asec/com.tapcrowd.ecommercebrasil-1/pkg.apk]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:466)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3264)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tapcrowd.app.TCApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/mnt/asec/com.tapcrowd.ecommercebrasil-1/pkg.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:461)
... 11 more
```

TCApplication is correctly referenced in the manifest.

I have tried adding external libraries by putting them in the libs folder, removing and adding library projects with no succes.

How can I prevent the crash?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tapcrowd.ecommercebrasil"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <!-- BEGIN GCM -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.tapcrowd.ecommercebrasil.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.tapcrowd.ecommercebrasil.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- END GCM -->

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name="com.tapcrowd.app.TCApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <service android:name="com.tapcrowd.app.service.UpdateService" />
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.tapcrowd.app.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

          ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Same issue here with version 22. Any ideas?

Comment: I fixed it by completely reinstalling eclipse and the android SDK

Comment: using eclipse, on an upgrade, i sometimes run the 'check for updates' an extra time and have to rerun updates on some of the modules that i want to install. Dont know why they are not picked up in the first update cycle.

Comment: This isue is pretty dated but I remeber that running 'check for updates' did not deliver any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by completely reinstalling eclipse and the android SDK